# AWS S3 website redirect not working

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-s3

I would love some help with this problem.

I have a website, e.g. example.me, that I am using AWS to host. The website is up and running fine.

I have followed the instructions found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/website-hosting-custom-domain-walkthrough.html to try redirect from www.example.me to example.me.

I am still getting a "Server not found" error on the www.example.me page, and have tried:

- deleting the bucket and creating a new one with new redirect
- adding my domain's name servers via Route 53
- adding in XML code and changing permissions of the bucket

I feel like I'm missing something small here as the instructions are not very difficult.

Comment: Before you do this, also check out how to publish your website using Cloudfront.  Because s3 data transfer going to cost you$0.09/GB. Massive bot request(e.g. search engine) or word case, DDoS happens, you are going to pay with your arm and leg.

Comment: Did you put the Route 53 DNS name into your Domain registration record ?

Comment: The process is indeed not very difficult but there are a number of errors you can make.  If you can tell us your domain name, it will greatly simplify the process.

Comment: For Michael, the domain name is: colemanrharris.me

Comment: For mootmoot, using the AWS instructions I don't believe that it is necessary to use Route 53. But for my main domain, yes the DNS name is in the registration record